# How do I store the value of my dropdownlist to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, dynamic

I've created a dynamic drop down list, but am totally clueless how to save the value into mysql database. Please help :'( I have tried several methods but none seems to work for me. These are my original codes.

**page2.php**

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

      <form action="page2insert.php" method="post"><br/>
         <table>
    <tr>
        <td>* Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pName" style="width: 300px" ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>* Type</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="pType" value="Student" checked>Student
            <input type="radio" name="pType" value="Staff">Staff (eg. Lecturer)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>* Class:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pClass" style="width: 200px" > If student</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>* Vote:</td>
        <td>
        <?php
         $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Name FROM DisplayImages ");

         echo '<select name="fselect">';

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
             echo "<option value='".$row['Name']."'>".$row['Name'] ."</option>";
         }
         echo "</select>";
         ?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>* Comment:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pComment" style="width: 300px" ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><center><input type="submit"></center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**page2insert.php**

```
<?php require_once("includes/connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
$sql="INSERT INTO Participants(Name, Type, Class, Vote, Comment)
VALUES
('$_POST[pName]','$_POST[pType]','$_POST[pClass]','$_POST[pVote]','$_POST[pComment]')";

// Executes query
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
{
    // die('Error:'.mysqli_error());
}
else
{
    $location="page1.php";
    header("Location:{$location}");
    echo "1 participant added".$sql;
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: On a quick look I couldn't see any mistakes, but like that you are very vulnerable to SQL injection, you have to verify that the values you receive are legal or at least double all the `'`. If I send you pComment = `whatever'); drop table participants; -- ` you might be in trouble.

Comment: @maraca Thanks for the tip! But I'm still unable to store my drop down list values to my sql database and would like to know how to fix that first :(

Comment: have you tested your database connection? and your other files can't do any output, header() has to be the first which does. An empty line not in php is already enough.

Comment: ... well I spotted an empty line, so if you remove that empty 3rd line in page2insert.php it might work (unless you have empty lines in your includes too).

Comment: also this will redirect so the echo after it is probably never displayed... you have to be more specific on what exactly is not working.

Comment: @maraca It doesn't show any error message, but the values in the drop down list are not stored in my database. It goes in blank.

Comment: You have to check your database, the blank is probably because of the reasons I explained above. Also if auto-commit is disabled you will have to commit yourself.